# eBay API - findItemsByProduct for Electronic Products by UPC code

Tags: ebay-api, ebay-lms

I don't know why, but I cannot login to eBay developer forum so that I am here to post a question about eBay API.

I am trying to look up a product by using UPC code with `findItemsByProduct` resource.
According to the official website (http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/finding/CallRef/findItemsByProduct.html),

> UPC—The UPC value for products in Music (e.g., CDs), DVD and Movie,
>   and Video Game categories (or domains). If you know a product's UPC
>   number, you can use this value instead of the eBay Reference ID to
>   search for that product.

Does this mean that we cannot look up Electronic products (e.g. laptop), using UPC code?
Actually, I have never seen yet any electronic products I could retrieve with UPC lookup.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

As long as a seller has entered a UPC when the item was listed it should be possible to find it via the API. However, entering a UPC is not supported by all categories. To determine if a category supports UPC you can call *GetCategoryFeatures* and check that the *UPCIdentifierEnabled* field is *true*.

Since calling *GetCategoryFeatues* on the US site (ID 0) for the category *Computers/Tablets & Networking > Laptops & Netbooks > PC Laptops & Netbooks (ID 177)* returns true in the *UPCIdentifierEnabled* field you should be able to search for laptops via UPC.

Beware that UPC is not used in all countries. For example European countries use EAN (European Article Number) instead. If you are searching on those sites you will need to check the value of the *EANIdentifierEnabled* field when calling *GetCategoryFeatures*.